# How to assign class properties dynamically using a record from MySQL database?

Tags: php, dynamic, properties

```
<?php

class User {

// properties

public $table = 'users';
public $id;
public $username ;
public $password ; 
public $first_name ;
public $last_name ;
```

Above (id, username..., last_name) are the column of **users** table in MySQL Database. After fetching(I'm using PDO) a specific record from **users** table using id, how can I assign all records to their respective properties dynamically(a function may help that will search through all available properties and search those properties in the resulting associative array and then assign those specific values to their respective properties)?

```
// methods

public function set_user($id){
    global $dbh;
    // sql
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE id = {$id}";
    // return result array
    $result_arr = $dbh->pdo_query_fetch($sql);
}
```

`$result_arr` contains associative array of id, username, password, first_name and last_name.

NOTE : Here `pdo_query_fetch()` is a user-defined function.

Comment: Take care when someones unsets the global variable `$dbh` your object would not work any longer. Instead inject the PDO connection when you create the object or use a setter method, that is more save and easier to change later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using PDO, it has that with `PDO::FETCH_INTO`:

```
PDO::query ( string $statement , int $PDO::FETCH_INTO , object $object )
```

See [PDO::query<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).

It might be that your "own" database class then is "owning" you, because you started to encapsulate things too early. This might require you to add an additional function to your `$dbh` class and/or you might want to start to refactor.

Comment: please a little more detail with an example.

Comment: You find an example in a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282962/php-pdo-do-the-fetch-styles-fetch-class-and-fetch-into-fetch-into-private-objec , it also demonstrates one of the other fetch-modes. Also there are various similar examples discussed in other questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747847/how-can-i-simply-return-objects-in-pdo and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986167/pdo-fetchobject-into-object-attributes-oop-in-php

Comment: your way is sweeter, i remove my answer and +1

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest adding a method to your user class:

```
public function Assign( $vars = array( ) )
{
    if( is_object( $vars )) {
      $this->Assign( get_object_vars( $vars ));
      return;
    }

    foreach ( $vars as $key => $value )
      if ( property_exists( $this, $key ) )
        $this->$key = $value;
}
```

With this method you can set properties from another object, or a array to your existing object.

You can use it like this:

```
myUser = new User();
myUser->Assign($result_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_object_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

```
$properties = get_object_vars($this);
foreach ($properties as $property => $property_value) {
  if (isset($result_arr[$property])) 
    $this->$property = $result_arr[$property];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to use `PDOStatement::fetchObject` ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php)) or `PDO::query` with `PDO::FETCH_INTO` flag ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)) but if there is no way to do that for some reasons:

```
foreach ($result_arr as $key => $value) {
    if (property_exists($user, $key)) {
       $user->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

also you can extend User class with __set :

```
public function __set($key, $value) {
    // do nothing
}
```

it will be called on every non-accessible property call (private or not defined)